# Como retornar vários campos como um único array ou string?

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo uma tabela no banco de dados com diversos telefones, o nome dos campos é numerado da seguinte forma: `telefone1, telefone2, telefone3` seu retorno é assim:

```
Array
(
    [telefone1] => 190
    [telefone2] => 197
    [telefone3] => 140
)
```

O que gostaria de fazer é no select, em vez de retornar vários telefones, retornar um array com todos, algo dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [telefone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 190
            [1] => 197
            [2] => 140
        )

)
```

Ou ainda unir os campos com algum caractere, por exemplo, vírgula:

```
190,197,140
```

Comment: Você quer retornar somente usando sql no sgbd ou em alguma IDE? poderia colocar a linguagem de programação que está usando? fiquei um pouco em dúvida!

Comment: A linguagem é php

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o comando `concat_ws`, na especificação, diz que uni string de acordo com um separador, melhor explicação em https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php
Seu select ficaria da seguinte forma `SELECT CONCAT_WS(" , ", telefone1, telefone2, telefone3) AS telefones` , lembrando que isso funciona se os telefones forem strings.